# How do I make a scatter plot of every variable in a set against every other variable in a set?

Tags: r

My code looks like this so far:

```
library(tidyverse)

load(Transport_Survey)

View(Transport_Survey)

variables <- names(Transport_Survey)

for (x in variables) {
  for (y in variables) {
    plot(x,y)
  }
}
```

Unfortunately I'm getting errors about introducing 'NaS' via coercision and things like 'In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf'

What can I do to remedy this?

Comment: Try `plot(Transport_Survey[[x]], Transport_Survey[[y]])`

Comment: To help you with search terms, if you're trying to lay all the scatterplots out together that's often called a scatterplot matrix

Comment: Does this answer your question? [r: Plotting each column against each column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36582772/r-plotting-each-column-against-each-column)

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the errors in the OP's code,  `x` and `y` refers to each of the column names and it is a string.  We need to extract the column from the dataset

```
for (x in variables) {
 for (y in variables) {
    plot(Transport_Survey[[x]], Transport_Survey[[y]])
 }
}
```

---

For scatter plot, an option is `pairs`

```
pairs(mtcars)
```

Comment: Hi, that's really helpful, thank you. Is there a way of showing the original variable name on the axes?