# How could I resolve the indexing error and plot graphs of every combination of two variables in R?

Tags: r, syntax-error

I'm trying to plot each variable in a set against every other variable in a set.

My code is as follows:

```
library(tidyverse)

load("Transport_Survey.RData")

variables <- select(Transport_Survey, one_of("InfOfReceievingWeather", "InfOfReceievingTraffic", "InfOfSeeingTraffic", "InfWeather.Ice", "InfWeather.Rain", "InfWeather.Wind", "InfWeather.Storm", "InfWeather.Snow", "InfWeather.Cold", "InfWeather.Warm", "InfWeather.DarkMorn", "InfWeather.DarkEve", "HomeParking", "WorkParking", "Disability", "Age", "CommuteFlexibility", "Gender", "PassionReduceCongest"))
varnames <- list("InfOfReceivingWeather", "InfOfReceivingTraffic", "InfOfSeeingTraffic", "InfWeather.Ice", "InfWeather.Rain", "InfWeather.Wind", "InfWeather.Storm", "InfWeather.Snow", "InfWeather.Cold", "InfWeather.Warm", "InfWeather.DarkMorn", "InfWeather.DarkEve", "HomeParking", "WorkParking", "Disability", "Age", "CommuteFlexibility", "Gender", "PassionReduceCongest")

counterx = 0
countery = 0

for (x in variables) {
  for (y in variables) {
    plot(Transport_Survey[[x]],Transport_Survey[[y]],
    xlab=varnames[counterx], ylab=varnames[countery])
    countery = countery+1
  }
  counterx = counterx+1
}


#variables2 <- select(Transport, one_of(InfOfReceivingWeather, InfOfReceivingTraffic, InfOfSeeingTraffic, InfWeather.Ice, InfWeather.Rain, InfWeather.Wind, InfWeather.Storm, InfWeather.Snow, InfWeather.Cold, InfWeather.Warm, InfWeather.DarkMorn, InfWeather.DarkEve, HomeParking, WorkParking, Disability, Age, CommuteFlexibility, Gender, PassionReduceCongest))
```

Unfortunately, I keep getting the following error:

```
Error in .subset2(x, i) : recursive indexing failed at level 2
```

I assume it's got something to do with the layered for loops or something, but I don't know what .subset2(x, i) is, nor how to approach solving it

Comment: Hello and welcome to stack. Firstly when you write a question can you provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example i.e. so that someone without any of your data can run your code (using `load` is no use for other people without your data file, best to provide `dput(Transport_Survey)` or `dput(head(Transport_Survey))`). Without your data a couple of guesses: `variables` is still a data.frame not the names of the columns so `Transport_Survey[[x]]` is looking for a whole df within the df. Also you are starting counterx at 0 but the first element is 1

Comment: Are you trying to do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36582772/r-plotting-each-column-against-each-column)?

Answer (score 0):

There might be some existing packages (functions) to do what you want. Just help you fix your code (indexing error), I use `mtcars` data:

```
library(tidyverse)
variables <- select(mtcars, c(mpg, hp, disp)) 
varnames <- list(names(variables))
for (x in varnames) {
    for (y in varnames) {
        plot(variables[x], variables[y]) 
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Zhiqiang has already helped you to fix the code but as R. Schifini has mentioned the best way is to use `pairs` to plot every combination of two variables. You can also extract all combinations of columns using `combn` and then plot them one by one or put them together using `par` as below:

Plotting using pairs might be the best

```
df <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/iris-data.csv')
pairs(df[,1:4]) # you only need the first four columns as you don't need class
```

If needed to remove duplicate plots

```
pairs(df[,1:4],upper.panel=NULL,pch=42)
```

[image]

If needed to plot them all in one plot using a loop (you can easily avoid plotting duplicates). Then you can do it with just one loop.

```
cm <- combn(names(df[,1:4]), 2, simplify=FALSE)
par(mfrow=c(2,3))
for(i in 1:length(cm)){
  plot(df[cm[[i]][1]][[1]], df[cm[[i]][2]][[1]], xlab = cm[[i]][1], ylab=cm[[i]][1])
}
```

[image]